# mat-form-field: Form field outline gap issue

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

so currently the outline on my project does not seem to work so I decided to add

```
 border: 1px solid #c4c4c4 !important;
  border-radius: 4px !important;
```

but there is still a gap as you can see on the 2 screenshots below  , anyone has an idea how to why the outline does not work ? Thanks.

#default  - using appearance outline

[image]

#these 2 screenshots are with border - custom one

[image]

[image]

#html code

```
<mat-form-field class="template-item-field" appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                <input [(ngModel)]="template.entitlementName" matInput placeholder="Entitlement Name">
            </mat-form-field>
```

#css code

```
.template-item-field {
  width: 200px;
  height: 51px;
  margin-left: 22.5px;
  margin-right: 22.5px;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4 !important;
  border-radius: 4px !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: inspect element on this input field, check the css tab, see why the outline is overridden and fix it! that is best!

Comment: been looking it for a while cant seem to find the css that overrides it

Comment: si there a way we can force or disable that ovveriding css without knowing where it is ?

Comment: can you check style.css for this line `@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`

Comment: yes , what do I look inside that css file bro ?

Comment: `@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';` add this line and check if outline gets added

Comment: still the same bro

Comment: is there a way I can overide it within my class file ? using ng deep ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247675/discussion-between-naren-murali-and-tim-launders).